# How do I know which nvidia graphics cards work with a Mac Pro?

Tags: hardware, mac-pro, gpu

I can't find a list of compatible graphics cards anywhere at the Apple web site and I can't find a list of compatible Apple machines anywhere at the nvidia web site. How does someone go about finding out these things?

In particular, does anyone know what the best performing CUDA-compatible graphics cards, compatible with the Mac Pro (MacPro5,1 and more recent) running Mountain Lion, with off-the-shelf drivers, are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be exactly what your looking for but [Bare Feats](http://www.barefeats.com/) has several articles on the current state (or lack there of) video cards for the Mac Pro.

Take a look at [CUDA compatible GPUs for the Mac Pro](http://www.barefeats.com/rogue02.html) and [Abandoning Apple 'Blessed' GPUs](http://www.barefeats.com/rogue01.html)

I recently had to replace a second dying NVidia 8800 GT in my Mac Pro (early 2008) but decided to stick with an Apple card.

Most of the non-Apple branded cards will not work until the machine is past the boot volume selection screen (if you need it) and I seem to find myself switching boot volumes frequently.

Comment: Those are the most helpful articles I've seen on this subject.